# Postgresql not importing all data from txt file

Tags: postgresql

I am importing a large amount of DATA ( 3000000 rows) in Postgresaql database from a txt file.
Each time I run my script, it imports only 1558 rows. It's new rows eah time, but I can't press  Run 3000 times :(.
Here is my entire script for importing the data.
I run the DB engine on my laptop.

''

```
Code service CH|Reference document|1 Articles CGI|2 Articles CGI|3 Articles CGI|4 Articles CGI|5 Articles CGI|No disposition|Date mutation|Nature mutation|Valeur fonciere|No voie|B/T/Q|Type de voie|Code voie|Voie|Code postal|Commune|Code departement|Code commune|Prefixe de section|Section|No plan|No Volume|1er lot|Surface Carrez du 1er lot|2eme lot|Surface Carrez du 2eme lot|3eme lot|Surface Carrez du 3eme lot|4eme lot|Surface Carrez du 4eme lot|5eme lot|Surface Carrez du 5eme lot|Nombre de lots|Code type local|Type local|Identifiant local|Surface reelle bati|Nombre pieces principales|Nature culture|Nature culture speciale|Surface terrain
|||||||000001|07/01/2020|Vente|8000,00||||B063|FORTUNAT|1250|CEYZERIAT|01|72||AK|216||||||||||||0||||||T||1061
|||||||000001|02/01/2020|Vente|2175,00||||B124|TERRES DES CINQ SAULES|1290|LAIZ|01|203||B|4||||||||||||0||||||BT||85
|||||||000001|02/01/2020|Vente|2175,00||||B006|BOIS DU CHAMP RION|1290|LAIZ|01|203||B|173||||||||||||0||||||T||1115
|||||||000001|02/01/2020|Vente|2175,00||||B025|EN COROBERT|1290|LAIZ|01|203||B|477||||||||||||0||||||T||1940
|||||||000001|02/01/2020|Vente|2175,00||||B124|TERRES DES CINQ SAULES|1290|LAIZ|01|203||C|68||||||||||||0||||||T||1148
|||||||000001|02/01/2020|Vente|2175,00||||B124|TERRES DES CINQ SAULES|1290|LAIZ|01|203||C|69||||||||||||0||||||T||2960
|||||||000001|07/01/2020|Vente|75000,00|||RUE|0064|DE LA CHARTREUSE|1960|PERONNAS|01|289||AI|210||||||||||||0||||||AB||610
|||||||000001|07/01/2020|Vente|123,00||||B041|CHAMP PORTIER|1370|VAL-REVERMONT|01|426||ZN|197||||||||||||0||||||S||55
|||||||000001|07/01/2020|Vente|123,00||||B041|CHAMP PORTIER|1370|VAL-REVERMONT|01|426||ZN|201||||||||||||0||||||S||68'





  /*
    
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';


-- ******************************
-- CREATION FONCTION PGCD
-- ******************************


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dvf.pgcd(valeurs integer[])
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
/*
  Retourne le Plus Grand Commun Diviseur de l'ensemble des valeurs du tableau d'entier.
  Si le tableau ne contient qu'un seul entier, Retourne sa valeur absolue.
 
  Exemple : SELECT pgcd(ARRAY[14,28,49,70]);
  7
 */
DECLARE
    v integer[];
    reste integer;
    a integer;
    b integer;
    gcd integer;
BEGIN
    v := valeurs;
    gcd := 0;
    IF array_length(v,1) > 1 THEN       
        a := v[1];  
        FOR i IN 2..array_upper(v,1)
        LOOP        
            b:=v[i];
            IF b<>0 THEN 
                LOOP
                    reste:=a%b;
                    a:=b;
                    b:=reste;
                    EXIT WHEN reste=0;
                END LOOP;
                
                IF abs(a) < gcd OR gcd = 0 THEN 
                    gcd := abs(a);
                    a := gcd;
                END IF;
                EXIT WHEN gcd=1;
            ELSE
                gcd=0;
                EXIT;
            END IF; 
        END LOOP;
    ELSE
        gcd = abs(v[1]);
    END IF;
        RETURN gcd;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT
  COST 100;



DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS import CASCADE ;
CREATE SCHEMA import;



CREATE TABLE import.dvf
(
    code_service_ch character varying(7),
    reference_document character varying(10),
    "1_articles_cgi" character varying(20),
    "2_articles_cgi" character varying(20),
    "3_articles_cgi" character varying(20),
    "4_articles_cgi" character varying(20),
    "5_articles_cgi" character varying(20),
    no_disposition integer,
    date_mutation date,
    nature_mutation character varying(34),
    valeur_fonciere character varying,  -- PASSE EN NUMERIC ENSUITE APRES AVOIR REMPLACE LES VIRGULES PAR DES POINTS
    no_voie integer,    
    b_t_q character varying(1),     
    type_de_voie character varying(4),  
    code_voie character varying(4),     
    voie character varying(254),        
    code_postal character varying(5),   
    commune character varying(254), 
    code_departement character varying(3),  -- COMPLETE ENSUITE PAR DES "0" SI NECESSAIRE
    code_commune character varying(3),      -- COMPLETE ENSUITE PAR DES "0" SI NECESSAIRE
    prefixe_de_section character varying(3),    -- COMPLETE ENSUITE PAR DES "0" SI NECESSAIRE
    section character varying(2),           -- COMPLETE ENSUITE PAR DES "0" SI NECESSAIRE
    no_plan character varying(4),           -- COMPLETE ENSUITE PAR DES "0" SI NECESSAIRE
    no_volume character varying(7),     
    "1er_lot" character varying(7),
    surface_carrez_du_1er_lot character varying,    -- PASSE EN NUMERIC ENSUITE APRES AVOIR REMPLACE LES VIRGULES PAR DES POINTS
    "2eme_lot" character varying(7),
    surface_carrez_du_2eme_lot character varying,   -- PASSE EN NUMERIC ENSUITE APRES AVOIR REMPLACE LES VIRGULES PAR DES POINTS
    "3eme_lot" character varying(7),
    surface_carrez_du_3eme_lot character varying,   -- PASSE EN NUMERIC ENSUITE APRES AVOIR REMPLACE LES VIRGULES PAR DES POINTS
    "4eme_lot" character varying(7),
    surface_carrez_du_4eme_lot character varying,   -- PASSE EN NUMERIC ENSUITE APRES AVOIR REMPLACE LES VIRGULES PAR DES POINTS
    "5eme_lot" character varying(7),
    surface_carrez_du_5eme_lot character varying,   -- PASSE EN NUMERIC ENSUITE APRES AVOIR REMPLACE LES VIRGULES PAR DES POINTS
    nombre_de_lots integer,
    code_type_local integer,            
    type_local character varying(254),
    identifiant_local character varying(10),
    surface_reelle_bati integer,
    nombre_pieces_principales integer,
    nature_culture character varying(2),            
    nature_culture_speciale character varying(5),   
    surface_terrain integer
);
```

COPY import.dvf FROM 'D:\Postgres_donnees\dvf\ValeursFoncieres-ZF590001-1114-2013.txt' WITH DELIMITER AS '|' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF-8' FORCE NOT NULL code_departement,code_commune ,prefixe_de_section ,section,no_plan;

```
CREATE TABLE import.dvf1 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        code_service_ch, reference_document, 
        "1_articles_cgi", "2_articles_cgi", "3_articles_cgi", "4_articles_cgi", "5_articles_cgi", no_disposition, 
        date_mutation, nature_mutation, 

        (replace(valeur_fonciere, ',', '.'))::numeric AS valeur_fonciere, 

                no_voie, b_t_q, 
        type_de_voie, code_voie, voie, code_postal, commune, 
        CASE WHEN code_departement NOT LIKE '97_' THEN lpad(code_departement, 2, '0') ELSE code_departement END AS code_departement,
        CASE WHEN code_departement NOT LIKE '97_' THEN lpad(code_commune, 3, '0') ELSE lpad(code_commune, 2, '0') END AS code_commune,
        lpad(prefixe_de_section, 3, '0') AS prefixe_de_section,
        lpad(section, 2, '0') AS section,
        lpad(no_plan, 4, '0') AS no_plan,
        no_volume, 
        "1er_lot", (replace(surface_carrez_du_1er_lot, ',', '.'))::numeric AS surface_carrez_du_1er_lot, 
        "2eme_lot", (replace(surface_carrez_du_2eme_lot, ',', '.'))::numeric AS surface_carrez_du_2eme_lot, 
        "3eme_lot", (replace(surface_carrez_du_3eme_lot, ',', '.'))::numeric AS surface_carrez_du_3eme_lot, 
        "4eme_lot", (replace(surface_carrez_du_4eme_lot, ',', '.'))::numeric AS surface_carrez_du_4eme_lot, 
        "5eme_lot", (replace(surface_carrez_du_5eme_lot, ',', '.'))::numeric AS surface_carrez_du_5eme_lot, 
        nombre_de_lots, code_type_local, 
        type_local, identifiant_local, surface_reelle_bati, nombre_pieces_principales, 
        nature_culture, nature_culture_speciale, surface_terrain,

        CASE WHEN code_departement NOT LIKE '97_' THEN lpad(code_departement, 2, '0') ELSE code_departement END||
            CASE WHEN code_departement NOT LIKE '97_' THEN lpad(code_commune, 3, '0') ELSE lpad(code_commune, 2, '0') END||
            lpad(prefixe_de_section, 3, '0')||lpad(section, 2, '0')||lpad(no_plan, 4, '0') 
        AS idpar,

        CASE WHEN no_voie IS NULL THEN '' ELSE no_voie::varchar END || '$' ||
            CASE WHEN b_t_q IS NULL THEN '' ELSE b_t_q END || '$' ||
            CASE WHEN code_voie IS NULL THEN '' ELSE code_voie END || '$' ||
            CASE WHEN type_de_voie IS NULL THEN '' ELSE type_de_voie END || '$' ||
            CASE WHEN voie IS NULL THEN '' ELSE voie END || '$' ||
            CASE WHEN code_postal IS NULL THEN '' ELSE code_postal END || '$' ||
            CASE WHEN commune IS NULL THEN '' ELSE commune END 
        AS idadr_tmp,
        
        CASE WHEN nature_culture IS NULL THEN '' ELSE nature_culture::varchar END || '$' ||
            CASE WHEN nature_culture_speciale IS NULL THEN '' ELSE nature_culture_speciale::varchar END || '$' ||
            CASE WHEN surface_terrain IS NULL THEN '' ELSE surface_terrain::varchar END
        AS idsuf_tmp
        
    FROM 
        import.dvf
);



    
INSERT INTO dvf.ann_nature_mutation(lib_nature_mutation)
(
    SELECT t.nature_mutation 
    FROM import.dvf t
    LEFT JOIN dvf.ann_nature_mutation t1 ON t.nature_mutation = t1.lib_nature_mutation
    WHERE t1.id_nature_mutation IS NULL
    GROUP BY t.nature_mutation
);



INSERT INTO dvf.mutat   code_service_ch, reference_document, date_mutation, id_nature_mutation
)
(
    SELECT t.code_service_ch, t.reference_document, t.date_mutation, t1.id_nature_mutation
    FROM import.dvf1 t
    LEFT JOIN dvf.ann_nature_mutation t1 ON t.nature_mutation=t1.lib_nature_mutation
    LEFT JOIN dvf.mutation t2 ON t.code_service_ch=t2.code_service_ch AND t.reference_document=t2.reference_document 
    WHERE t2.id_mutation IS NULL
    GROUP BY t.code_service_ch, t.reference_document, t.date_mutation, t1.id_nature_mutation
    --ORDER BY t.code_service_ch, t.reference_document, t.date_mutation, t1.id_nature_mutation
);



INSERT INTO dvf.disposition 
(
    id_mutation, no_disposition, valeur_fonciere,nombre_de_lots
)
(
    SELECT tt.id_mutation, tt.no_disposition, tt.valeur_fonciere, array_agg(tt.nombre_de_lots) AS nombre_de_lots
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t2.id_mutation, t.no_disposition, t.valeur_fonciere, t.nombre_de_lots
        FROM import.dvf1 t
        LEFT JOIN dvf.mutation t2 ON t.code_service_ch=t2.code_service_ch AND t.reference_document=t2.reference_document
        LEFT JOIN dvf.disposition t3 ON t2.id_mutation=t3.id_mutation AND t.no_disposition=t3.no_disposition
        WHERE id_disposition IS NULL
        GROUP BY t2.id_mutation, t.no_disposition,t.valeur_fonciere, t.nombre_de_lots
        --ORDER BY t2.id_mutation, t.no_disposition,t.valeur_fonciere
    ) tt
    GROUP BY tt.id_mutation, tt.no_disposition, tt.valeur_fonciere
);



INSERT INTO dvf.parcelle 
(
    idpar, code_departement, code_commune, prefixe_de_section, section, no_plan
)
(
    SELECT 
        t.idpar,
        t.code_departement,
        t.code_commune,
        t.prefixe_de_section,
        t.section,
        t.no_plan
    FROM import.dvf1 t
    LEFT JOIN dvf.parcelle t4 ON t.idpar=t4.idpar
    WHERE t4.id_parcelle IS NULL
    GROUP BY t.idpar, t.code_departement, t.code_commune, t.prefixe_de_section, t.section, t.no_plan
    --ORDER BY t.idpar, t.code_departement, t.code_commune, t.prefixe_de_section, t.section, t.no_plan
);



INSERT INTO dvf.disposition_parcelle 
(
    id_disposition, id_parcelle--, nombre_de_lots
)
(
    SELECT t3.id_disposition, t4.id_parcelle--, max(t.nombre_de_lots)
    FROM import.dvf1 t
    LEFT JOIN dvf.mutation t2 ON t.code_service_ch=t2.code_service_ch AND t.reference_document=t2.reference_document 
    LEFT JOIN dvf.disposition t3 ON t2.id_mutation=t3.id_mutation AND t.no_disposition=t3.no_disposition
    LEFT JOIN dvf.parcelle t4 ON t.idpar=t4.idpar
    LEFT JOIN dvf.disposition_parcelle t5 ON t3.id_disposition=t5.id_disposition AND t4.id_parcelle=t5.id_parcelle
    WHERE t5.id_dispoparc IS NULL
    GROUP BY t3.id_disposition, t4.id_parcelle
    --ORDER BY t3.id_disposition, t4.id_parcelle
);




CREATE TABLE import.dvf2 AS
(
    SELECT 
        t5.id_dispoparc,
        t3.id_disposition, 
        t4.id_parcelle,
        -- pour table "volume"
        no_volume, 
        -- pour table "lot"
        "1er_lot", surface_carrez_du_1er_lot, "2eme_lot", surface_carrez_du_2eme_lot, 
        "3eme_lot", surface_carrez_du_3eme_lot, "4eme_lot", surface_carrez_du_4eme_lot, 
        "5eme_lot", surface_carrez_du_5eme_lot, 
        -- pour table "local"
        code_type_local, type_local, identifiant_local, surface_reelle_bati, nombre_pieces_principales,
        -- pour table "suf" 
        nature_culture, nature_culture_speciale, surface_terrain,
        -- pour table "adresse"
        no_voie, b_t_q, type_de_voie, code_voie, voie, code_postal, commune,
        -- pour tous
        idadr_tmp, idsuf_tmp
    FROM import.dvf1 t
    LEFT JOIN dvf.mutation t2 ON t.code_service_ch=t2.code_service_ch AND t.reference_document=t2.reference_document 
    LEFT JOIN dvf.disposition t3 ON t2.id_mutation=t3.id_mutation AND t.no_disposition=t3.no_disposition
    LEFT JOIN dvf.parcelle t4 ON t.idpar=t4.idpar
    LEFT JOIN dvf.disposition_parcelle t5 ON t3.id_disposition=t5.id_disposition AND t4.id_parcelle=t5.id_parcelle
);
CREATE INDEX dvf2_id_dispoparc_btree_idx ON import.dvf2 USING BTREE(id_dispoparc);



INSERT INTO dvf.adresse 
(
    no_voie, b_t_q, code_voie, type_de_voie, voie, code_postal, commune, idadr_tmp
)
(
    SELECT t.no_voie, t.b_t_q, t.code_voie, t.type_de_voie, t.voie, t.code_postal, t.commune, t.idadr_tmp
    FROM import.dvf1 t
    LEFT JOIN dvf.adresse t6 ON t.idadr_tmp=t6.idadr_tmp
    WHERE t6.id_adresse IS NULL
    GROUP BY t.no_voie, t.b_t_q, t.code_voie, t.type_de_voie, t.voie, t.code_postal, t.commune, t.idadr_tmp
    ORDER BY t.no_voie, t.b_t_q, t.code_voie, t.type_de_voie, t.voie, t.code_postal, t.commune, t.idadr_tmp
);



INSERT INTO dvf.local 
(
    id_dispoparc, identifiant_local, code_type_local, nombre_pieces_principales, surface_reelle_bati
)
(
    SELECT t.id_dispoparc, t.identifiant_local, t.code_type_local, t.nombre_pieces_principales, t.surface_reelle_bati
    FROM import.dvf2 t
    LEFT JOIN dvf.local t7 ON t.id_dispoparc=t7.id_dispoparc AND t.identifiant_local=t7.identifiant_local
    WHERE 
        t7.id_local IS NULL
        AND t.identifiant_local IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY t.id_dispoparc, t.identifiant_local, t.code_type_local, t.nombre_pieces_principales, t.surface_reelle_bati
    ORDER BY t.id_dispoparc, t.identifiant_local, t.code_type_local, t.nombre_pieces_principales, t.surface_reelle_bati
);

-----------------
-- volume
-----------------
INSERT INTO dvf.volume 
(
    id_dispoparc, no_volume
)
(
    SELECT t.id_dispoparc, t.no_volume
    FROM import.dvf2 t
    LEFT JOIN dvf.volume t8 ON t.id_dispoparc=t8.id_dispoparc AND t.no_volume=t8.no_volume
    WHERE 
        t8.id_volume IS NULL
        AND t.no_volume IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY t.id_dispoparc, t.no_volume
    ORDER BY t.id_dispoparc, t.no_volume
);

-----------------
-- suf 
-----------------
--> Creation d'une table temporaire avec le nombre de sufs identiques non nulles
----DROP TABLE IF EXISTS import.tmp_suf;
CREATE TABLE import.tmp_suf AS
(
    SELECT
        id_dispoparc, count(*) as nb_suf_idt, surface_terrain, nature_culture, nature_culture_speciale, idsuf_tmp
    FROM 
        import.dvf2 t1
    WHERE
        nature_culture IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 
        id_dispoparc, surface_terrain, nature_culture, nature_culture_speciale, idsuf_tmp
);
CREATE INDEX tmp_suf_id_dispoparc_btree_idx ON import.tmp_suf USING BTREE(id_dispoparc);

INSERT INTO dvf.suf 
(
    id_dispoparc, nb_suf_idt, surface_terrain, nature_culture, nature_culture_speciale, idsuf_tmp
)
(
    SELECT
        t1.id_dispoparc, t1.nb_suf_idt/t2.pgcd_nb_suf_idt AS nb_suf_idt, t1.surface_terrain*t1.nb_suf_idt/t2.pgcd_nb_suf_idt AS surface_terrain, t1.nature_culture, t1.nature_culture_speciale, t1.idsuf_tmp
    FROM 
        import.tmp_suf t1
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT id_dispoparc, dvf.pgcd(array_agg(nb_suf_idt)::integer[]) AS pgcd_nb_suf_idt FROM import.tmp_suf GROUP BY id_dispoparc) t2
    ON
        t1.id_dispoparc=t2.id_dispoparc
    LEFT JOIN
        dvf.suf t3
    ON 
        t1.id_dispoparc=t3.id_dispoparc
    WHERE
        t3.id_dispoparc IS NULL
);


----DROP TABLE IF EXISTS import.tmp_suf;

-----------------
-- id_lot (id_suf, id_local et id_volume enlevés)
-----------------
INSERT INTO dvf.lot
(
    id_dispoparc, id_local, id_suf, id_volume, no_lot, surface_carrez
)
(
    SELECT t1.id_dispoparc, t3.id_local, t4.id_suf, t5.id_volume, 1 as no_lot, surface_carrez_du_1er_lot
    FROM import.dvf2 t1
    LEFT JOIN dvf.lot t2 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t2.id_dispoparc AND t2.no_lot=1
    LEFT JOIN dvf.local t3 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t3.id_dispoparc AND t1.identifiant_local=t3.identifiant_local
    LEFT JOIN dvf.suf t4 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t4.id_dispoparc AND t1.idsuf_tmp=t4.idsuf_tmp
    LEFT JOIN dvf.volume t5 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t5.id_dispoparc AND t1.no_volume=t5.no_volume
    WHERE 
        t1."1er_lot" IS NOT NULL 
        AND t2.id_lot IS NULL
    GROUP BY t1.id_dispoparc, t3.id_local, t4.id_suf, t5.id_volume, surface_carrez_du_1er_lot
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT t1.id_dispoparc, t3.id_local, t4.id_suf, t5.id_volume, 2 as no_lot, surface_carrez_du_2eme_lot
    FROM import.dvf2 t1
    LEFT JOIN dvf.lot t2 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t2.id_dispoparc AND t2.no_lot=2
    LEFT JOIN dvf.local t3 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t3.id_dispoparc AND t1.identifiant_local=t3.identifiant_local
    LEFT JOIN dvf.suf t4 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t4.id_dispoparc AND t1.idsuf_tmp=t4.idsuf_tmp
    LEFT JOIN dvf.volume t5 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t5.id_dispoparc AND t1.no_volume=t5.no_volume
    WHERE 
        t1."2eme_lot" IS NOT NULL 
        AND t2.id_lot IS NULL
    GROUP BY t1.id_dispoparc, t3.id_local, t4.id_suf, t5.id_volume, surface_carrez_du_2eme_lot
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT t1.id_dispoparc, t3.id_local, t4.id_suf, t5.id_volume, 3 as no_lot, surface_carrez_du_3eme_lot
    FROM import.dvf2 t1
    LEFT JOIN dvf.lot t2 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t2.id_dispoparc AND t2.no_lot=3
    LEFT JOIN dvf.local t3 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t3.id_dispoparc AND t1.identifiant_local=t3.identifiant_local
    LEFT JOIN dvf.suf t4 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t4.id_dispoparc AND t1.idsuf_tmp=t4.idsuf_tmp
    LEFT JOIN dvf.volume t5 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t5.id_dispoparc AND t1.no_volume=t5.no_volume
    WHERE 
        t1."3eme_lot" IS NOT NULL 
        AND t2.id_lot IS NULL
    GROUP BY t1.id_dispoparc, t3.id_local, t4.id_suf, t5.id_volume, surface_carrez_du_3eme_lot
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT t1.id_dispoparc, t3.id_local, t4.id_suf, t5.id_volume, 4 as no_lot, surface_carrez_du_4eme_lot
    FROM import.dvf2 t1
    LEFT JOIN dvf.lot t2 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t2.id_dispoparc AND t2.no_lot=4
    LEFT JOIN dvf.local t3 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t3.id_dispoparc AND t1.identifiant_local=t3.identifiant_local
    LEFT JOIN dvf.suf t4 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t4.id_dispoparc AND t1.idsuf_tmp=t4.idsuf_tmp
    LEFT JOIN dvf.volume t5 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t5.id_dispoparc AND t1.no_volume=t5.no_volume
    WHERE 
        t1."4eme_lot" IS NOT NULL 
        AND t2.id_lot IS NULL
    GROUP BY t1.id_dispoparc, t3.id_local, t4.id_suf, t5.id_volume, surface_carrez_du_4eme_lot
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT t1.id_dispoparc, t3.id_local, t4.id_suf, t5.id_volume, 5 as no_lot, surface_carrez_du_5eme_lot
    FROM import.dvf2 t1
    LEFT JOIN dvf.lot t2 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t2.id_dispoparc AND t2.no_lot=5
    LEFT JOIN dvf.local t3 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t3.id_dispoparc AND t1.identifiant_local=t3.identifiant_local
    LEFT JOIN dvf.suf t4 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t4.id_dispoparc AND t1.idsuf_tmp=t4.idsuf_tmp
    LEFT JOIN dvf.volume t5 ON t1.id_dispoparc=t5.id_dispoparc AND t1.no_volume=t5.no_volume
    WHERE 
        t1."5eme_lot" IS NOT NULL 
        AND t2.id_lot IS NULL
    GROUP BY t1.id_dispoparc, t3.id_local, t4.id_suf, t5.id_volume, surface_carrez_du_5eme_lot

);

-----------------
-- mutation_article_cgi
-----------------
INSERT INTO dvf.mutation_article_cgi
(
    id_mutation, id_article_cgi, ordre_article_cgi
)
(
    SELECT t2.id_mutation, t3.id_article_cgi, 1 AS ordre_article_cgi
    FROM import.dvf t
    LEFT JOIN dvf.mutation t2 ON t.code_service_ch=t2.code_service_ch AND t.reference_document=t2.reference_document  
    LEFT JOIN dvf.ann_cgi t3 ON t."1_articles_cgi"=t3.article_cgi
    LEFT JOIN dvf.mutation_article_cgi t4 ON t2.id_mutation=t4.id_mutation AND 1=t4.ordre_article_cgi
    WHERE 
        t."1_articles_cgi" IS NOT NULL 
        AND t4.id_mutation IS NULL
    GROUP BY t2.id_mutation, t3.id_article_cgi
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT t2.id_mutation, t3.id_article_cgi, 2 AS ordre_article_cgi
    FROM import.dvf t
    LEFT JOIN dvf.mutation t2 ON t.code_service_ch=t2.code_service_ch AND t.reference_document=t2.reference_document  
    LEFT JOIN dvf.ann_cgi t3 ON t."2_articles_cgi"=t3.article_cgi
    LEFT JOIN dvf.mutation_article_cgi t4 ON t2.id_mutation=t4.id_mutation AND 2=t4.ordre_article_cgi
    WHERE 
        t."2_articles_cgi" IS NOT NULL 
        AND t4.id_mutation IS NULL
    GROUP BY t2.id_mutation, t3.id_article_cgi
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT t2.id_mutation, t3.id_article_cgi, 3 AS ordre_article_cgi
    FROM import.dvf t
    LEFT JOIN dvf.mutation t2 ON t.code_service_ch=t2.code_service_ch AND t.reference_document=t2.reference_document  
    LEFT JOIN dvf.ann_cgi t3 ON t."3_articles_cgi"=t3.article_cgi
    LEFT JOIN dvf.mutation_article_cgi t4 ON t2.id_mutation=t4.id_mutation AND 3=t4.ordre_article_cgi
    WHERE 
        t."3_articles_cgi" IS NOT NULL 
        AND t4.id_mutation IS NULL
    GROUP BY t2.id_mutation, t3.id_article_cgi
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT t2.id_mutation, t3.id_article_cgi, 4 AS ordre_article_cgi
    FROM import.dvf t
    LEFT JOIN dvf.mutation t2 ON t.code_service_ch=t2.code_service_ch AND t.reference_document=t2.reference_document  
    LEFT JOIN dvf.ann_cgi t3 ON t."4_articles_cgi"=t3.article_cgi
    LEFT JOIN dvf.mutation_article_cgi t4 ON t2.id_mutation=t4.id_mutation AND 4=t4.ordre_article_cgi
    WHERE 
        t."4_articles_cgi" IS NOT NULL 
        AND t4.id_mutation IS NULL
    GROUP BY t2.id_mutation, t3.id_article_cgi
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT t2.id_mutation, t3.id_article_cgi, 5 AS ordre_article_cgi
    FROM import.dvf t
    LEFT JOIN dvf.mutation t2 ON t.code_service_ch=t2.code_service_ch AND t.reference_document=t2.reference_document  
    LEFT JOIN dvf.ann_cgi t3 ON t."5_articles_cgi"=t3.article_cgi
    LEFT JOIN dvf.mutation_article_cgi t4 ON t2.id_mutation=t4.id_mutation AND 5=t4.ordre_article_cgi
    WHERE 
        t."5_articles_cgi" IS NOT NULL 
        AND t4.id_mutation IS NULL
    GROUP BY t2.id_mutation, t3.id_article_cgi
);

-----------------
--> TABLE TEMPORAIRE POUR TABLE DE CORRESPONDANCE AVEC ADRESSES
-----------------

----DROP TABLE IF EXISTS import.tmp_adresse_dispoparc_local;
CREATE TABLE import.tmp_adresse_dispoparc_local AS
(
    SELECT t3.id_adresse, t2.id_local, t.id_dispoparc
    FROM import.dvf2 t
    LEFT JOIN dvf.local t2 ON t.id_dispoparc=t2.id_dispoparc AND t.identifiant_local=t2.identifiant_local
    LEFT JOIN dvf.adresse t3 ON t.idadr_tmp=t3.idadr_tmp
);

    -----------------
    -- adresse_dispoparc
    -----------------
    INSERT INTO dvf.adresse_dispoparc 
    (
        id_adresse, id_dispoparc
    )
    (
        SELECT t1.id_adresse, t1.id_dispoparc
        FROM import.tmp_adresse_dispoparc_local t1
        LEFT JOIN dvf.adresse_dispoparc t2
        ON t1.id_adresse=t2.id_adresse AND t1.id_dispoparc=t2.id_dispoparc
        WHERE 
            t1.id_adresse IS NOT NULL
            AND t1.id_dispoparc IS NOT NULL
            AND t2.id_adresse IS NULL
            AND t2.id_dispoparc IS NULL
        GROUP BY t1.id_adresse, t1.id_dispoparc
        --ORDER BY id_adresse, id_dispoparc
    );

    -----------------
    -- adresse_local
    -----------------
    INSERT INTO dvf.adresse_local 
    (
        id_adresse, id_local
    )
    (
        SELECT t1.id_adresse, t1.id_local
        FROM import.tmp_adresse_dispoparc_local t1
        LEFT JOIN dvf.adresse_local t2
        ON t1.id_adresse=t2.id_adresse AND t1.id_local=t2.id_local
        WHERE 
            t1.id_adresse IS NOT NULL
            AND t1.id_local IS NOT NULL
            AND t2.id_adresse IS NULL
            AND t2.id_local IS NULL
        GROUP BY t1.id_adresse, t1.id_local
        --ORDER BY id_adresse, id_dispoparc
    );
    
    
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS import.dvf;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS import.dvf1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS import.dvf2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS import.tmp_adresse_dispoparc_local;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS import.tmp_suf;

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS import ;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you also add a sample from this text file of yours? Also add the table structure where it should be imported to (preferably create table statements).

Comment: Code service CH|Reference document|1 Articles CGI|2 Articles CGI|3 Articles CGI|4 Articles CGI|5 Articles CGI|No disposition|Date mutation|Nature mutation|Valeur fonciere|No voie|B/T/Q|Type de voie|Code voie|Voie|Code postal|Commune|Code departement|Code communet|5eme lot|Surface Carrez du 5eme lot|Nombre de lots|Code type local|Type local|Identifiant local|Surface reelle bati|Nombre pieces principales|Nature culture|Nature culture speciale|Surface terrain
|||||||000001|07/01/2020|Vente|8000,00||||B063|FORTUNAT|1250|CEYZERIAT|01|72||AK|216||||||||||||0||||||T||1061

Comment: All tables creation code are like:   `code` -- table mutation_article_cgi
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dvf.mutation_article_cgi;
CREATE TABLE dvf.mutation_article_cgi
(
 id_mutation integer,
 id_article_cgi integer,
 ordre_article_cgi integer,
 CONSTRAINT mutation_article_cgi_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_mutation,id_article_cgi)
 --CONSTRAINT mutation_article_cgi_unique UNIQUE (id_mutation, id_article_cgi,ordre_article_cgi)
);
COMMENT ON TABLE dvf.mutation_article_cgi IS 'Table des articles du code général des impôts (cgi) attachés à la mutation';`code`

Comment: Thank you for youe welcome. This phenomena sounds really weired.

Comment: Your "entire script" just defines a function which doesn't load any data, and then randomly cuts off in the middle of defining a table.

Comment: please edit your question and add the sample data in the question rather than in comment

Comment: It's my forst post here, I hope this time the format is right.